# Find the general solution of differential equation. Help!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Find the general solution of the equation:

$$\dfrac{d^3y}{dx^3} + \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\csc x $$

I am getting $y=c-1+c-2\cos x+c_3 \sin x-\ln(\csc x+\cot x)-\cos x(\ln(\sin x))-x \sin x $

All seems relatively correct except $-\ln(\csc x+\cot x)$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you need help?

Comment: [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%27%27+%2B+y%27+%3D+csc%5Bx%5D)

Comment: I have tried to use variation of parameters and so far yc= c1+c2cosx+c3sinx.... does it make a difference if yc is in different order like yc=c1sinx+c2cosx+c31

Comment: Need help with particular solution

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for the particular solution seems correct to me. It's just another formulation. You made some mistakes in the complementary solution. Complementary solution should be :
$$y_h=c_1+c_2 \cos x + c_3 \sin x$$
For the particular solution, you have :
$$ E=-\ln(\csc x+\cot x)$$
$$ E=-\ln(\frac 1 {\sin(x)}+\frac {\cos x}{\sin x})$$
Use trigonometric substitution $t=\tan (x/2), \sin x= \frac {2t}{1+t^2}, \cos x =\frac {1-t^2}{1+t^2}$
$$E=-\ln (\frac 1 t )$$
$$E=\ln t \implies E=\ln(\tan(x/2))$$
That's the expression you find in Wa solution.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%27%27+%2B+y%27+%3D+csc+x

Answer (score 0):

$$ y'''+y'=0 $$
$$y=e^\alpha e^x $$ $$\Rightarrow $$
$$\alpha^3+\alpha=0 $$ $\alpha_1=0 $ $\alpha_2=i $ $ \alpha_3=-i $
$$y(x)=C_1cos(x)+C_2sin(x)+C_3  $$
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
C'_1cos(x)+C'_2sin(x)+C'_3=0 \\ 
-C'_1sin(x)+C'_2cos(x)=0\\ 
-C'_1cos(x)-C'_2sin(x)=\frac{1}{sin(x)}
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
you are left to solve this system with respect to variables $$C'_1,C'_2,C'_3 $$

Comment: does it matter if for y(x) i have =c1+c2cosx+c3sinx

Comment: does it make a difference?

Comment: it's basically the same thing

Comment: In my solution $$C_1(x)=-ln(sin(x))+C_1 $$ $$C_2(x)=C_2  $$ $$C_3(x)=ln(2tan^-1x) +C_3$$

Comment: By the way, you asked another question about differential equations and I solved it, can you check it? ;)